# MySql: Ecommerce product variant structure

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, database-diagrams

I have a problem with the database organization for ecommerce product variations. Googling, I found a lot of articles and every article says that if the product has more variations, it should be in a separate table with a relation. Each variation (sku) has its own price etc...

What interests me is the following: Where do I store the price of the product if the product does not have a variation? For example, the product is in one color, one size!

Can someone look at my diagram and suggest if I'm doing something wrong?

The first picture shows a product with variations, while the second picture shows a product without variations

[image: Db schema]
is this scheme good or bad?

Comment: Let's see the `SELECTs` for typical queries.

Comment: This is table organisation no quering

Comment: But the schema organization can make queries easy and fast -- or not.  Without knowing what the schema is designed for, I cannot judge the schema by itself.

Comment: I dont know whay you waste your and my time... if here for you not enought to see table organisation on picture go read another question where is table represented with `Create Table products, attributes`. Second, i dont tell nothing for how to make query....

Comment: I guess we agree to disagree.  I am not good at e-commerce, maybe someone else is.  Take a look at Woocommerce.